# package androidx.core.content does not exist

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, androidx, capacitor, ionic5

I am trying to run Ionic 5 app on android with the below command

```
ionic cap run android -l --external --verbose
```

but getting these errors

```
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
[capacitor]         C:\xxx\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\java\de\appplant\cordova\emailcomposer\Provider.java:22: error: package androidx.core.content does not exist
[capacitor]         import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;
[capacitor]         ^
[capacitor]         C:\xxx\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\java\de\appplant\cordova\emailcomposer\Provider.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
[capacitor]         public class Provider extends FileProvider {
[capacitor]         ^
[capacitor]         symbol: class FileProvider
[capacitor]         C:\xxx\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\java\com\pdf\generator\PDFGenerator.java:68: error: cannot access androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
[capacitor]         final Context ctx = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
[capacitor]         ^
[capacitor]         class file for androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity not found
[capacitor]         C:\xxx\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\java\de\appplant\cordova\emailcomposer\EmailComposer.java:109: error: incompatible types: androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity cannot be converted 
to android.content.Context
[capacitor]         return cordova.getActivity();
[capacitor]         ^
[capacitor]         C:\xxx\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\java\de\appplant\cordova\emailcomposer\AssetUtil.java:276: error: cannot find symbol
[capacitor]         return Provider.getUriForFile(ctx, authority, file);
[capacitor]         ^
[capacitor]         symbol:   method getUriForFile(android.content.Context,java.lang.String,java.io.File)
[capacitor]         location: class de.appplant.cordova.emailcomposer.Provider
[capacitor]         Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[capacitor]         Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[capacitor]         5 errors
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         > Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource
[capacitor]         > Task :app:processDebugResources
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         * What went wrong:
[capacitor]         Execution failed for task ':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
[capacitor]         > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         * Try:
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
[capacitor]         Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
[capacitor]         See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[capacitor]         152 actionable tasks: 42 executed, 110 up-to-date
[capacitor]         Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         BUILD FAILED in 45s
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         C:\xxx\android>if "1" == "0" goto mainEnd
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         C:\xxx\android>rem Set variable GRADLE_EXIT_CONSOLE if you need the _script_ return code instead of
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         C:\xxx\android>rem the _cmd.exe /c_ return code!
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         C:\xxx\android>if not "" == "" exit 1
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         C:\xxx\android>exit /b 1
[capacitor]
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess capacitor.

        capacitor.cmd run android --no-sync --target ce01182192619a1301 exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: 'process.exit' received +0ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: running 6 functions +0ms
  ionic:lib:hooks Looking for ionic:serve:after npm script. +54s
  ionic:utils-process error while killing process tree for 5752: Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 5752 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERROR: The process "5752" not found.
  ionic:utils-process 
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 5752 /T /F'
```

I have been trying to find a solution for the last three days with no luck. I have done following to fix it but its still showing same error

in gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

in variables.gradle

```
 minSdkVersion = 23
    compileSdkVersion = 30
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    androidxActivityVersion = '1.2.0'
    androidxAppCompatVersion = '1.2.0'
    androidxCoordinatorLayoutVersion = '1.1.0'
    androidxCoreVersion = '1.3.2'
    androidxFragmentVersion = '1.3.0'
    junitVersion = '4.13.1'
    androidxJunitVersion = '1.1.2'
    androidxEspressoCoreVersion = '3.3.0'
    cordovaAndroidVersion = '10.1.1'
```

in build.gradle

```
repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
... 
... 
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

None of these changes fixes the issue. However, if I open android build in Android Studio with

```
ionic cap open android
```

and add library 'Gradle:androidx.core:core:1.3.0@aar' to class path as intellisense suggestion then it works and and I can run the project on device from Android studio.
[image]
But if I make changes and rebuild then it shows same error again.

Environment detail

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.16.3 (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.6.11
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 12.0.5
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 12.0.5
   @angular/cli                  : 12.0.5
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 4.0.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 3.1.1
   @capacitor/android : 3.3.2
   @capacitor/core    : 3.3.2
   @capacitor/ios     : not installed

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.3
   native-run  : 1.4.0

System:

   NodeJS : v14.16.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.14.11
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Please suggest any solution for this.

Many Thanks

Comment: Have you found any solution of this? If yes, please tell.

Comment: no, still haven't found a solution. for now have removed email-composer module that was causing this issue

Comment: have you found solution ya?

Comment: nope, haven't fond any solution. That project is on hold but will start again soon

Answer (score 1):

try these steps:

1. `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx`
2. `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter`

> if still not working try step:

3. 

```
npm install jetifier    
npx jetifier    
npx cap sync android
```

Comment: have already done these

Comment: @Bhavesh what version of JAVA are you using? try updating java to latest version

Comment: have added environment detail in question

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Capacitor, you cannot "add plugin" like in Cordova...

You have to install it from npm or yarn.

```
npm i cordova-plugin-androidx
npm i cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter....
```

Or try to update to the latest Capacitor, Ionic and Android Studio.

Comment: have tried installing plugins from npm and updating ionic but still same error.  here's what I have
Ionic CLI 6.16.2
Ionic Framework: 5.6.11
Angular : 12.0.5
Capacitor CLI: 3.1.1
Capacitor Core: 3.3.1

Have added full detail in question